# Stable solution for Bluetooth connecting issue

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, bluez, bluetooth-speaker

I can see the Bluetooth connecting issue (More common with Bluetooth headset/speaker) is common problem in Ubuntu or Linux. (I use ubuntu 18.04). I could not get a fixed solution for that. I have a bluetooth headset and I always struggle to connect that,also it is same for other bluetooth devices (Probably devices with audio profiles). I have all the module installed that need for connecting with bluetooth(Such as `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`,`module-bluetooth-discover`) and all the pacjages are updated.I have read many articles, None of that helped me for zero struggle solution. Behavior of connecting issue is very random.

In most times very first pair of Bluetooth device work perfectly in even gui settings. It all occur from the next connect of the same device. It shows device is connected when powering on the device, but it suddenly disconnect before it properly connected.

Some times it perfectly connect at first attempt. Some times I need to remove the device and then pair again. Sometimes even device is connected not showing as output device in sound. Sometimes it fixes with restarting the `blutooth` service. Sometimes I need to reboot.

It works without any issue with both Android and Windows.

GUI Bluetooth setting most times fail. I mostly try with `bluetoothctl`. 
Ihave installed **blueman** and it also fails when connecting. Here are outputs of `bluetoothctl` of both fail and successful states.

[image: error connect]
[image: success connect]

So where does the issue lie in? Is it `Bluez` api or `pulseaudio` or somewhere else?